# I tansfered ownership of my wallet to a program. How can I set it back to SystemProgram?

Tags: anchor, systemprogram

I played around with Anchor and put my wallet pubkey in the newAccount field.
Now my wallet is assigned to my program.
So I it can't pay for transaction fees anymore.

https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2Qbx6EyD6yhJPzx7WbCcYDNzTQQ5oymiuNXfytCip1LrFkXg57sfJ5TDhfgt4f1UmqZ3NxP2LZAtmDkHfkDqCo83?cluster=devnet

Can I reverse that somehow or do I need to create a new account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens to people accidentally, so for taking back your wallet you must transfer all lamports from it with new instructions (your program is the new owner of your wallet and can do anything with that without any signature).
after that reallocate the space in the account to 0 and then reassign the owner of the account to the system program.

Cheers